# How to add an object in reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a store that looks like this, 3 objects within an array that carry array. How can I add an object in between the first and second object that carry index 1 and 2?

```
{
  object: [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "title": "title",
      "caption": "caption",
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "title": "title",
      "caption": "caption",
    },
    {
      "index": 3,
      "title": "title",
      "caption": "caption",
    },
  ]
}
```

Would like to have the final output like this after clicking a button that pass in the index value of 1.

```
{
  object: [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "title": "title",
      "caption": "caption",
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "title": "NEW",
      "caption": "NEW",
    },
    {
      "index": 3,
      "title": "title",
      "caption": "caption",
    },
    {
      "index": 4,
      "title": "title",
      "caption": "caption",
    },
  ]
}
```

I can use the following codes to change the index value through action, but how to add another new object in between object 1 and object 2, plus changing the index value at the same time?

```
switch (action.type) {
  case ADDCOMPONENT:
    return {
      ...state,
      object: state.object.map(component =>
          (component.index > action.index ?
          { ...component, index: component.index + 1 } : component)),
    };
```

Comment: Are you asking how to change the shape of your state in your store? Or how to manipulate the data you can from the store and insert and object into an array at a specific index?

Answer (score 1):

```
smth.object.splice(index, 0, item);
```

And don't keep item index as a string. You can easily get position of item in array, and then add 1 to the value

Answer (score 1):

```
state.object.splice(component.index, 0, component);
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

The shape of your `store` is created by the combination of all your reducers. The data that you want to update your store with should be created in your application and then sent to your reducer with `dispatch(action)`. The `reducer` takes the information on the `action` and updates your state accordingly. If you want to add an object into an array you can use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) as follows: `myArray.splice( startIndex, 0, itemsToInsert, ... )`.

In short, don't add the object in your reducer. Add it to the data you are sending in your action, before you send the action.

If you would like to be able to insert things into an array and not mutate them, you should think about using a function like the one in this snippet:

```js
function nonMutatingArrayInsert( array, index, insert ) {
 // return array if index is outside range of array
        if ( index < 0 || index > array.length - 1 ) return array;  

        // ensure insert is array for concat purposes
        let _insert = Array.isArray( insert ) ? insert : [ insert ];

 // handle 0 index insert
 if ( index === 0 ) { return [ ..._insert, ...array ]; }

 // handle end of array insert
 if ( index === array.length ) { return [ ...array, ..._insert ] }

 // handle everyhing else
 const before = array.slice( 0, index );
 const after = array.slice( index, array.length );

 // return new non-mutated array
 return [ ...before, ..._insert, ...after ];
}

let myArray = [ "one", "four" ];

let newArray = nonMutatingArrayInsert( myArray, 1, ["two", "three"] );

console.log( "myArray:\n", myArray );
console.log( "newArray:\n", newArray );
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Have moved out the code from reducer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers seem to miss the point that you need to increment the indexes of the other objects in the array. I'd approach it in two steps: first adding the new object with [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), then looping through and incrementing all subsequent indexes.

```
var index = 1;
state.object.splice(index, 0, new_component); //Insert the new object

//Starting where you inserted, add one to all later components
for (var i = index +1; i < state.object.length; i++) {
    state.object[i].index ++;
}
```

After this `state` holds the value you want.

However, I'd encourage you to think about if the objects really need to know where they are in the array. In my experience, any code that would need to access the objects would be able to tell where they are in the array.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers works, however in order to not mutate the array, I have used the following codes instead.

Slice the array before and insert the new object in between.

```
  let newObject = state.portfolio.components.slice(0, action.index);
  newObject = newObject.concat(NEWOBJECT);
  newObject = newObject.concat(state.portfolio.components.slice(action.index));

  for (let i = action.index; i < newComponent.length; i++) {
    newComponent[i].index = i + 1;
  }
```

Replace the object with the newObject.

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADDCOMPONENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        object: newObject,
      };
```

EDITED: Used immutability-helper in the end with simpler codes without mutating.

```
  return update(state, {
    portfolio: {
      object: {
        $splice: [
          [action.index + 1, 0, action.newObject],
        ],
      },
    }
  });
```